# not working ccs style javafx -fx-strikethrough

Tags: java, css, javafx

I want to make text strikethrough using CSS.

I use tag:

```
button.setStyle("-fx-strikethrough: true;");
```

But this code is working, please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a CSS stylesheet to enable strikethrough on a button.  Using a CSS stylesheet is usually preferable to using an inline CSS setStyle command anyway.

```
/** file: strikethrough.css (place in same directory as Strikeout) */
.button .text {
    -fx-strikethrough: true;
}
```

The CSS style sheet uses a CSS selector to select the text inside the button and apply a strikethrough style to it.  Currently (as of Java 8), setStyle commands cannot use CSS selectors, so you must use a CSS stylesheet to achieve this functionality (or use inline lookups, which would not be advisable) - the style sheet is the best solution anyway.

See @icza's answer to understand why trying to set the `-fx-strikethrough` style directly on the button does not work.

[image: strikethrough]

Here is a sample application:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Strikeout extends Application {

    @Override 
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Button strikethrough = new Button("Strikethrough");
        strikethrough.getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getResource(
                "strikethrough.css"
        ).toExternalForm());

        StackPane layout = new StackPane(
                strikethrough
        );
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Comment on the use of strikethough versus disable**

I would add that, if you want to strikethrough the text on a button, you probably also want to disable the button, which you can do by calling [`button.setDisable(true)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#disableProperty).  When you do this, it will make the button non-functional and provide a visible indication that it is disabled.  By default, this visible indication will be that the text on the button is greyed out.  Usually, this would be a preferable approach to styling the button text with strikethough.

Answer (score 5):

[`Button`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html) does not support the `-fx-strikethrough` CSS property, so setting this has no effect.

Here is the official JavaFX 8 CSS reference: [**JavaFX CSS Reference Guide**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)

The `-fx-strikethrough` is defined for the `Text` node.

`Button` only supports the following: `cancel`, `default`, and all inherited from `Labeled`:

```
-fx-alignment, -fx-text-alignment, -fx-text-overrun, -fx-wrap-text, -fx-font, 
-fx-underline, -fx-graphic, -fx-content-display, -fx-graphic-text-gap,
-fx-label-padding, -fx-text-fill, -fx-ellipsis-string
```

And `Labeled` inherits these from `Control`: `-fx-skin`, `-fx-focus-traversable`.

So looking at the supported properties, the following works (of course it's not strikethrough):

```
button.setStyle("-fx-underline: true");
```

Comment: Thanks you. I attentively watched.

Comment: is there any way to make the text on the button strikethrough?